# event.keyCode not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im appending an `input` to my `html` markup but my event listener not working on this `input`
here is my code:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('body').append('<input>')
})
$('input').on('keydown',function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13){
     alert('ok')
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: use delegate instead of on

Comment: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20event%20dynamically%20created%20element

Comment: @uzaif i did its not working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGdmRM

Comment: `$('body').on('keydown','input',function(e){});` add event like this so that it gets binded to input elements even if they are created later

Comment: $('button').click(function(){
  $('body').append('<input id="test">')
})
$('body').on('keydown',"input",function(e){
  // alert(e.keyCode);
  if(e.keyCode==13){
     alert('ok')
    }
})

Answer (score 0):

try event delegation:

```
$('body').on('keydown','input',function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==13){
     alert('ok')
    }
})
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaQVym